# Trying to see if this is responsive

Tags: html, css

Review the basic CSS below, confirm whether this will provide a responsive page or not.  If not, what changes would need to take place for it to be responsive?

```
  <style>
.article {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: Do you know something about responsive? Improve your question with more data about your code or what you want to do.

Comment: Seems like homework.

Answer (score 1):

A lot goes into "making a site responsive". One simple set of instructions alone will not do it. But if your question meant - "how to make this particular section responsive?" then you may want to start with this:

```
<style>
    .article {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 33%; /* Flexible widths   */
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    } 
</style>
```

Again, this alone will not do it. These are some, but not all, that goes into RWD

- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

> A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling. The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device). The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

- Get acquainted with `@media` queries - Read [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
- RWD Frameworks - Employ a Responsive framework to save you some of the footwork. I recommend Bootstrap. Find it [**here**](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Responsive CSS can be characterized as using measurements based on a percentage of screen size or incorporating the use of media queries.

Non-fixed unit measurements

```
.article {
  float: left;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300vh;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Media query within a stylesheet

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .article {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```